# Android notification won't show up as a heads up notification

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I am using the following code to show my notification:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.notification_general_id))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iit)
                    .setContentTitle("something")
                    .setContentText(notification)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251192/2287994
    long time = new Date().getTime();
    String tmpStr = String.valueOf(time);
    String last4Str = tmpStr.substring(tmpStr.length() - 5);
    int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(last4Str);
    Log.d(TAG, "notificationId " + notificationId);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

I create notification channel using the following code:

```
    // for showing general notifications
    NotificationChannel generalNotificationsChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            getString(R.string.notification_general_id),
            getString(R.string.notification_general_name),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    );
    nearbyAnchorsChannel.setDescription(getString(R.string.notification_general_desc));

    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

On Google Pixel 3a, the notification only vibrates and shows up as a blip on the top left. However, on the OnePlus 6, it shows up as a proper heads-up notification that we can immediately swipe or tap on. I tried looking through the settings of my Pixel 3a (it is Android 12) but I cannot find any option that I can change to enable a heads-up display of notifications. Tbh, I am not even sure if there is something wrong with my code or the phone I am testing it on. Is it because of my OnePlus 6's Android version (it is Android 11)? Or is it due to the code that I have written? If it is due to the former then can someone please explain to me how I can change settings on my Pixel 3a to show a proper swipeable heads-up notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, when you change channel importance, you need to uninstall the app and install it again. That's why it worked on the OnePlus 6 (because I installed it after changing the notification importance) and not on the Google Pixel 3a (because I was still working with the same install)